# UIScrollView with previews of page left and right

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin.ios

I want to have a scrollview with views inside that a user can swipe left or right and interact with it. The scrollview has UIViews inside that a user needs to interact with.

[image: scrollview]

I have been able to add the views and it works okay with Paging Enabled. Unfortunately, I don't seem to find a good way of showing previews.

There's a post at a [UIScrollview Paging Hack](http://www.inediblesoftware.com/blog/2009/04/05/uiscrollview-paging-hack/), that explains how to deal with it. The solution has three problems:

- It works only if the previews are 1/4 of the width of the center image. I originally thought I found a formula to deal with the size of the previews, but as the number of slides changed I was wrong.
- If the width of the previews are not the 1/4 of the width the sliding works, but the center slide becomes offset from the center.
- The current slide doesn't have UI interaction enabled unless it's the first one (and part of what's visible). When you slide to other sections, I can't use buttons.

I've searched a lot on the web on how to do this, and haven't been able to find a solution. Suggestions are welcomed even in Objective C.

**UPDATE**: I have come up with a solution that does what I describe here. https://github.com/roland/Carousel/tree/master/Carousel

Comment: Could you set the scroll view frame to the one you actually want, with paging enabled, but set clipsToBounds=NO so the content will show beyond the paging frame?

Comment: I tried it and the problem is that the slide immediately left or right is skipped over when you scroll. I need the preview to move into the center after a swipe, as if to indicate a snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution that does what I describe here. https://github.com/roland/Carousel/tree/master/Carousel

Answer (score 1):

There was a piece of Address Book sample code from last year’s WWDC—I think it was called PhotoBook—that showed how to accomplish this. Basically, this is the setup you need:

- A scroll view with a width of (the width of each content page) + (the desired padding space between the pages)
- Page content positioned inside the scroll view, at X positions of (the page index) * ((the page width) + (the padding space)) - 0.5 * (the padding space)
- A subclassed view containing the scroll view, with its `-hitTest:withEvent:` method overridden to always return the scroll view it contains

Comment: ! Thanks. The first two line items, were pretty much what I had. The last item, withTest was interesting, but for the subclass of scrollview it was always returning the same coordinates, and returning the current instance didn't make it the motion stop. I'm currently investigating whether setContentOffset is the way to go. I can calculate what frame index one is on, and checking whether the animation is decelerating seems to be somewhat decent. I'll post it on github once I'm done.

Comment: Don't subclass the scroll view itself—subclass a generic UIView that's the size of the whole visible area that you want to be scrollable, and make your scroll view a subview of that. The whole point of this trick is that you can then set `pagingEnabled` to `YES` on the scroll view and it’ll handle deceleration/centering for you.

Comment: I don't want to impose. I tried to find the wwdc presentation from 2010 and couldn't find what you're describing. Maybe, there's a trick I don't see. however, I did come up with a solution that does what I wanted https://github.com/roland/Carousel/tree/master/Carousel . Thanks for your help.